# How to use entity framework in other modules?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am currently developing  project using C# MVC and entity framework, I want to use the entity framework in other modules ,

i.e security module , Utility module ,

i want to call the db using the entity frame work, how do i do this ?
 i am new to this are please explain   in detail, idea is to break the project into presentation layer, business layer and data access layer..
 i don't know how to archive this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way,

There are three ways to work around entity framework, Database First, Model First & Code First.
Database First: If you already have database, then entity framework can generate a data model that consists of classes & properties that correspond to existing database objects such as tables & columns.
The information of database structure, conceptual data model & mapping between them is store in the xml in an .edmx file.

Model First: If you don't have database, you can start creating model using vs entity framework designer. This approach also use the .edmx file.

Code First: In this approach, we don't need .edmx file. Mapping between store schema & conceptual data model is represented by code, handled by code convention & special mapping API.

Here I have used the Database First approach. 
[image]

In order to use the Dal class lib, add the reference in the business logic layer and initialize the entities class. For example

1. Find the entity framework object.
   [image]
2. Initialize the entity framework object in other class lib.

   FrameworkEntities entities = new FrameworkEntities();

Please let me know, if you want to use model first or code first approach.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I need model first approach.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg685494.aspx. I hope, this will help you to create entity classes & properties using model first approcah.

Answer (score 0):

Get started from the below link for the Entity Frame Work
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/ee712907?